# Return document data after set/add operation in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get back some info about the document I just created/updated without making a second request.

I know that I get back a Document reference with the Id of the document, but I need additional info like createTime and updateTime.

Currently, this is the way I'm trying to achieve that, but I would like to spare that extra request since it's not very efficient.

```
const docRef = await database.collection('tagsCollection').add({
    ...input
    createTime: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});

const doc = await docRef.get();

return {
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
    createTime: doc.data().createTime.toMillis().toString()
};
```

Comment: So where do createTime and updateTime come from, if not your client code?  Are you using a server timestamp?  Something in Cloud Functions?  There must be something else going on here that I can't see.

Comment: It is added automatically by Firestore, but you can assume that I added it because that is basically what I’m trying to do.

Comment: I didn't notice it wasn't in the docs. But no, it's not a private implementation, those are properties returned from the `docRef.get()` query.

Answer (score 0):

Since those fields come from Firestore on the server side, it's safe to assume that the client doesn't know what they are until a DocumentSnapshot has been queried.  You could perhaps make a guess on your own, but you're essentially trying to guess what the round trip latency is for your call to `add()`.

Comment: I did add some properties of my own for tracking creation and update times before finding out that firestore adds those automatically.
In that case I used `serverTimestamp`, however, I had the same issue because the `serverTimestamp` is set on the server, but I wanted to return it.

The issue is not specific to those fields, its just in general. ill update the code above for better example.

Comment: Unless the actual value originates on the client, I don't think you're going to be able to use it without making a query.  It sounds like you might be trying to optimize something that's not even a performance problem yet?